# Is there any way to overcome the glitch in Mass Effect 3 that results in Eve dying with Maelon's data available and prior missions complete?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've played through the game three times now on Xbox 360 with imported characters, and can't seem to save Eve, no matter what I do. I've saved Maelon's data, had all possible missions complete before doing "Priority: Tuchanka," chosen all paragon in favour of the Krogan, and tried both to talk to Eve on Normandy and to not talk to her (the second was a suggestion found online.) I've read in a few places that it's a glitch. Is there any way to resolve the glitch so I can finish the game without being P.O.'d that my choices weren't a factor in this particular outcome of the game? It's getting exceedingly annoying.

Comment: I hate to say it, but if you want your choices to factor into the outcome of the game, ME3 may not be the game for you.

Comment: As much as I agree that all "choices" lead to the same general ending, there's little details that change. I just want to see Eve and Wrex happy at the end of the game. My brother has played a few times and saved Eve, and since I'm borrowing his game, I know it's possible. I also know I'm choosing the same "choices" that he did. It's silly, but I want to see it in the ending cutscene.

Comment: On PC I managed to save her. Try not to tell her about the tower sabotage and not to talk her too much.

Comment: If I may ask what patch number are you on

Answer (score 1):

Only imported characters from ME2 can save Eve, since there you had an option to Save Maelon's Research Data in an **OPTIONAL** (yet recommended to go through) mission. That's right - you need to have played ME2 to do this... and ME1 to have Urdnot Wrex too (he's kind of important).

Yeah, playing ME3 alone is not recommended, if you want all the collectibles.

You could probably download a ME2 save-file which has all those "right choices" made, and have ME3 import from that.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions that they are playing with imported characters and saved Maelon's data, so I'm not sure how this answers the question.